# Unit Tests in Angular can't read 'setValidators' of null

Tags: angular

Actually I am writing Test Cases in spec file for one of the components in our solution. We are using FormGroup and using some validation in it like this-

**my component contains-**

```
export class FormFieldInputV2Component implements OnInit, AfterViewInit {

  @Input() configData: any;
  @Input() frmGroup: FormGroup;
  @Input() frmBuilder:FormBuilder;

  constructor() {}
  
  placeHolder = "";
  validationType: string = "";

  @ViewChild('formFieldWrapper', null) formFieldWrapper;
  
  

    ngOnInit() {
    
        this.configData.validation.forEach((element) => {
          if (element === "Numeric") {
            this.validationType = element;
            this.frmGroup.get(this.configData.name).setValidators(Validators.min(1));
            this.frmGroup
              .get(this.configData.name)
              .setValidators(Validators.pattern(new RegExp("^0*[1-9]\\d*$")));
          } else if (element === "Decimal") {
            this.validationType = element;
            this.frmGroup.get(this.configData.name).setValidators(Validators.min(1));
            this.frmGroup
              .get(this.configData.name)
              .setValidators(
                Validators.pattern(
                  new RegExp("^\\s*(?=.*[1-9])\\d*(?:\\.\\d{1,99})?\\s*$")
                )
              );
          } else if (element === "DecimalWithMaxlength") {
            this.validationType = element;
            this.frmGroup
              .get(this.configData.name)
              .setValidators(
                Validators.pattern(
                  new RegExp(/^\s*(?=.*[1-9])\d{1,3}(?:\.\d{1,2})?\s*$/)
                )
              );
          }
          if (element === "NoSpecialCharacter") {
            this.validationType = element;
            this.frmGroup
              .get(this.configData.name)
              .setValidators(
                Validators.pattern(new RegExp("^((?![$<>?%&*#!~` +]).).*\\S*$"))
              );
          }
          if (element === "Email") {
            let newexp = /^(([^<>()\[\]\\.,;:\s@"]+(\.[^<>()\[\]\\.,;:\s@"]+)*)|(".+"))@((\[[0-9]{1,3}\.[0-9]{1,3}\.[0-9]{1,3}\.[0-9]{1,3}\])|(([a-zA-Z\-0-9]+\.)+[a-zA-Z]{2,}))$/;
            this.validationType = element;
            this.frmGroup
              .get(this.configData.name)
              .setValidators(Validators.pattern(newexp));
          }
          if (element === "hidden") {
            if (!(this.frmGroup.get(this.configData.name)["hidden"] === false)) {
              this.frmGroup.get(this.configData.name)["hidden"] = true;
            }
          }
        }, this);
      }
    
        ngAfterViewInit() {
          this.frmGroup.get(this.configData.name).statusChanges.subscribe(x => {
              if(this.frmGroup.get(this.configData.name).value == undefined || this.frmGroup.get(this.configData.name).value == null){
                this.formFieldWrapper.nativeElement.classList.remove("dhl-form-field--is-active",
                  "dhl-form-field--set-borderRed", "dhl-form-field--set-border-success", "dhl-form-field--is-filled");
              }
          });
        }
```

**My Spec Contains-**

```
fdescribe('FormFieldInputV2Component', () => {

  let component: FormFieldInputV2Component;

  let fixture: ComponentFixture<FormFieldInputV2Component>;

  beforeEach(() => {

    fixture = TestBed.createComponent(FormFieldInputV2Component);

    component = fixture.componentInstance;
    
    component.frmGroup = formBuilder.group({
      firstName: null,
      lastName: null
    });

    fixture.detectChanges();
    component.ngOnInit();
    fixture.detectChanges();
  });

  it('should create', () => {

    expect(component).toBeTruthy();
  });

  it('should run #ngAfterViewInit()', async () => {

  it('form should be invalid', async(() => {

      fixture.detectChanges();

      component.frmGroup.get(component.configData.name).setValidators(Validators.min(5));

      expect(component.frmGroup.valid).toBeFalsy();
    }));
  
    it('form should be valid', async(() => {
      component.frmGroup.get(component.configData.name).setValidators(Validators.min(1));
      expect(component.frmGroup.valid).toBeTruthy();
    }));

    component.configData.name = 'name';
    component.configData.validation=["NoSpecialCharacter"];
    component.formFieldWrapper = component.formFieldWrapper || {};
    component.formFieldWrapper.nativeElement = {
      classList: {
        remove: function() {}
      }
    };
    component.ngAfterViewInit();
  });

  // new test by ngentest

  it('should run #onBlurSetActive()', async () => {

    component.configData = component.configData || {};

    component.configData.placeHolder = 'placeHolder';

    component.configData.validation=["NoSpecialCharacter"];

    component.onBlurSetActive({}, {});

  });
```

After running ng test it gives me error 'FormFieldInputV2Component should run #ngAfterViewInit() FAILED
TypeError: Cannot read property 'setValidators' of null'

Comment: please help for this, as I already spent more then a day to solve it, but no luck.

Comment: No need to beg for help in the comments. Your post is enough. Sometimes it takes a few minutes.

Comment: now after modifications, I am doing this-                                                                                         formGroupMock = new FormGroup({
      name : new FormControl()
    });

    formBuilderMock = jasmine.createSpyObj('FormBuilder', ['get']);
    formBuilderMock.get.and.returnValue(formGroupMock);

    formGroupMock.patchValue({
      name :'orderCreatedDate'
    });                                                                                                                                               but it's not orking and giving same issue

Answer (score 0, accepted):

i am not sure but i think in beforeEach block instead of setting formgroup properties to null you need to assign them formControls

```
component.frmGroup = formBuilder.group({
      firstName: new FormControl(),
      lastName: new FormControl()
    });
```

you are trying to call setValidator on null in ngOnInit

Comment: I tried this approach, but still getting same error!

Comment: make sure the name of the form control is same as you are trying to access and form group has controls with that name

Comment: actually in our ts we have not defined any new controls for Form Group, we are directly accessing get method of Form Group

Comment: thnks to all, and the last suggestion worked for me. thank @jagjeet

Answer (score 0):

I looks that you didn't provide the configData in you spec file, i assume the error is being through on this statement

```
component.frmGroup.get(component.configData.name).setValidators(Validators.min(5));
```

and at this point in your test component.configData is undefined.
To solve the issue you need to assign a vlaue to the configData similar to what you did to the FormGroup in beforeEach
beforeEach(() => {

```
fixture = TestBed.createComponent(FormFieldInputV2Component);

component = fixture.componentInstance;

component.frmGroup = formBuilder.group({
  firstName: null,
  lastName: null
});

// here you need to provide a valid data
component.configData = //whatever valid data

fixture.detectChanges();
component.ngOnInit();
fixture.detectChanges();
```

});

Comment: it is also not working, but thnks for effort. I am providing the correct data for component.configData but still no luck.

Answer (score 0):

There are few missing things here:

- You need to import the FormBuilder in the providers
- Add your component in the declaration
- Use `it('name of test, ()=>{function})` inside your `fdescribe`, you are using multiple `it()` inside one, and that will throw an error.

```
  let component: FormFieldInputV2Component;

  let fixture: ComponentFixture<FormFieldInputV2Component>;

  beforeEach(() => {

    let configData: any;
    let frmGroup: FormGroup;
    let formBuilder: FormBuilder;

    TestBed.configureTestingModule({
      imports: [],
      declarations: [FormFieldInputV2Component],
      providers: [FormBuilder]
    }).compileComponents();
    fixture = TestBed.createComponent(FormFieldInputV2Component);
    component = fixture.componentInstance;
  });
```

**The complete file from your post can look something like this:**

```
import { NgModule } from "@angular/core";
import { async, ComponentFixture, TestBed } from "@angular/core/testing";
import { FormBuilder, FormGroup, Validators } from "@angular/forms";
import { FormFieldInputV2Component } from "./form-field-input-v2-component.component";

fdescribe('FormFieldInputV2Component', () => {

  let component: FormFieldInputV2Component;

  let fixture: ComponentFixture<FormFieldInputV2Component>;

  beforeEach(() => {

    let configData: any;
    let frmGroup: FormGroup;
    let formBuilder: FormBuilder;

    TestBed.configureTestingModule({
      imports: [],
      declarations: [FormFieldInputV2Component],
      providers: [FormBuilder]
    }).compileComponents();
    fixture = TestBed.createComponent(FormFieldInputV2Component);
    component = fixture.componentInstance;
  });

  it('should create', () => {
    expect(component).toBeTruthy();
  });

  it('should run #ngAfterViewInit()', async () => {
    fixture.detectChanges();

    component.frmGroup.get(component.configData.name).setValidators(Validators.min(5));
    expect(component.frmGroup.valid).toBeFalsy();

    component.frmGroup.get(component.configData.name).setValidators(Validators.min(1));
    expect(component.frmGroup.valid).toBeTruthy();

    component.configData.name = 'name';
    component.configData.validation = ["NoSpecialCharacter"];
    component.formFieldWrapper = component.formFieldWrapper || {};
    component.formFieldWrapper.nativeElement = {
      classList: {
        remove: function () { }
      }
    };
    component.ngAfterViewInit();
  });


  // new test by ngentest
  
  it('should run #onBlurSetActive()', async () => {
  
    component.configData = component.configData || {};
  
    component.configData.placeHolder = 'placeHolder';
  
    component.configData.validation=["NoSpecialCharacter"];
  
    component.onBlurSetActive({}, {});
  
  });
});
```

Comment: most of the things are already like this in my file also, but still I modified some of the changes as per suggested by You to match exactely like Yours, thanks for help, but still it's not working :(

Answer (score 0):

now after modifications, I am doing this-

```
let formGroupMock: FormGroup;
  let formBuilderMock: any;                                                                                   formGroupMock = new FormGroup({
      name : new FormControl()
    });

    formBuilderMock = jasmine.createSpyObj('FormBuilder', ['get']);
    formBuilderMock.get.and.returnValue(formGroupMock);

    formGroupMock.patchValue({
      name :'orderCreatedDate'
    });          

                                                                                                                                 but it's not working and giving same issue
```

Comment: but my above answer is also giving same issue. :(